# How can I create explosions like in Zelda: Breath of the Wild?

Tags: rendering

The explosions in BotW look spectacular. Here's a video of them in slow motion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZtaNoUOSDQ

It looks like it's not all billboards, but also some volumetric geometry - it's hard to see all the details.

Ideally, an answer would be API agnostic, but I am using OpenGL with a homemade renderer, if that helps.

Which techniques are combined to create such a fantastic effect?

Comment: You should include in the question what framework you're using.

Comment: I'm not using any framework.

Comment: No OpenGL, no Direct3D, no language?

Comment: I think this can be answered in a framework/rendering-API-agnostic fashion and that doing so would make a more useful question _and_ answer. Providing some guidance on what you're using may result in answers better suited to that API for you, though.

Comment: It seems to me like there is quite a lot of different techniques going on there. I don't think that there is a simple answer to this question.

Comment: I am perfectly fine with a complex answer. A list of all those techniques would be great.

Comment: Philipp's concern isn't that a complex answer would be a burden to you. It's that it could be a burden to people trying to answer. Remember these folks are unpaid, volunteering time away from their own game development projects to help you. The more time they need to invest in reverse-engineering and reproducing a complicated effect, the less likely you are to find someone who's got the time and skills to do all that for free. If you can do some of the legwork of examining these effects and breaking them down into pieces, then asking about a specific piece, you may get better answers, faster.